# Rxjs GroupBy, Reduce in order to Pivot on ID

Tags: rxjs

I'm looking for a bit of help understanding this example taken from the rxjs [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-groupBy).

```
Observable.of<Obj>({id: 1, name: 'aze1'},
                       {id: 2, name: 'sf2'},
                       {id: 2, name: 'dg2'},
                       {id: 1, name: 'erg1'},
                       {id: 1, name: 'df1'},
                       {id: 2, name: 'sfqfb2'},
                       {id: 3, name: 'qfs1'},
                       {id: 2, name: 'qsgqsfg2'}
                      )
        .groupBy(p => p.id, p => p.name)
        .flatMap( (group$) => group$.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], ["" + group$.key]))
        .map(arr => ({'id': parseInt(arr[0]), 'values': arr.slice(1)}))
        .subscribe(p => console.log(p));
```

So the aim here is to group all the items by id and produce an object with a single ID and a values property which includes all the emitted names with matching IDs.

The second parameter to the groupBy operator identifies the return value. Effectively filtering the emitted object's properties down to the name. I suppose the same thing could be achieved by mapping the observable beforehand. Is it possible to pass more than one value to the return value parameter?

The line I am finding very confusing is this one:

```
.flatMap( (group$) => group$.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], ["" + group$.key]))
```

I get that we now have three grouped observables (for the 3 ids) that are effectively arrays of emitted objects. With each grouped observable the aim of this code is to reduce it an array, where the first entry in the array is the key and subsequent entries in the array are the names.

But why is the reduce function initialized with `["" + group$.key]`, rather than just `[group$.key]`?

And why is this three dot notation `[...acc, cur]` used when returning the reduced array on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is the reduce function initialized with `["" + group$.key]`, rather than just `[group$.key]`?

The clue to answer this question is in the `.map()` function a bit further down in the code.

```
.map(arr => ({'id': parseInt(arr[0]), 'values': arr.slice(1)}))
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Note the  use `parseInt`. Without the `"" +` in the `flatMap` this simply wouldn't compile since you'd be passing a number type to a function that expects a `string`. Remove the `parseInt` and just use `arr[0]` and you can remove `"" +` as well.

> And why is this three dot notation `[...acc, cur]` used when returning
>   the reduced array on each iteration?

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) here is used to add to the array without mutating the array. But what does it do? It will copy the original array, take all the existing elements out of the array, and deposit the elements in the new array. In simpler words, take all elements in `acc`, copy them to a new array with `cur` in the end. [Here is a nice blog post about object mutation in general.](https://slemgrim.com/mutate-or-not-to-mutate/)

Comment: Great, that's helpful, thanks. The transformation of the number into a string then back again just seemed pointless, which was what threw me. I've not come across the spread operator before. I'll read up.